# Easy Diameter protocol implementaion using Java

Tags: java, diameter-protocol

I need help on how to implement Diameter protol using Java.
I was going through weblogic diameter API, but hard to understand.

Comment: Good to know, but how we can help You ?

Comment: If you have any good document to understand the diameter protocol implementation using Java

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old post but maybe it will help somebody.

The simplest implementation I have found is jDiameter stack
You can find some examples on the web that will help you build some programs with that. The best one is: [diameter-educational-series-creating](http://baranowb.blogspot.com/2010/11/diameter-educational-series-creating.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well.... there are open sources examples, but you should remember:

1. DIAMETER is a wrapper standard -- the actual format of the AVPs,
   their structure, their serialization etc. is entirely vendor
   defined.
2. DIAMETER is agnostic as to whether encryption is to be used, and
   what form is to be used.

You can get 'simulations" of DIAMETER, but without knowing the AVPs, their format, encryption rules etc.  you're likely left with little more than TCP stream of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Ericsson Diameter SDK contains Java implementation of the protocol.

Download the client and server and look into the java codes